# Can I launch a Windows exe with a simulated reduced amount of RAM?

Tags: windows, memory

I have an older application that crashes on launch on a Windows 7-64 bit machine.  The root cause, according to the internets, is apparently I have too much memory and the app has some bug when it sees more than 4 (3.5) GB of RAM.

Can I launch the exe with command line arguments telling the app I have less memory?  Or create a launcher process with restricted memory?  Anything from command line, batch scripts, to win32 code is fair game for me.

I realize it's a long shot, but I welcome any suggestions, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried a virtual machine?

Comment: Yeah I thought about using Windows XP Mode but I am not on Professional.  I could do a virtual PC and install a full Win 7 virtual, but I am holding that as my backup plan.  Thanks for the comment though!

Comment: Right-click on the shortcut, select `Properties`, then `Compatability`. Check `Run this program in compatibility mode` and select the OS the application was designed to run under.

Comment: @David A good idea which I tried before I posted.  That causes an external file pathing issue with the app.  Thanks though!

Comment: @David I finangled some settings with a related app, and in combination with running in compatibility mode I got this to work.  If you want to post your comment as an answer I will mark as accepted, thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right-click on the shortcut, select `Properties`, then `Compatability`. Check `Run this program in compatibility mode` and select the OS the application was designed to run under.

Answer (score 1):

For a tremendous overkill waste of resources, run windows inside a virtual machine and control the amount of RAM using the VM.  Again, this is using overkill to fix this.  The only reason I would do this is to not have to make any changes on my computer AND if I expected the code writer to have a fix AND if the easy answer (David Schwartz answer) didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If setting compatibility modes do not work then you can try:

- Taking out a stick of RAM so that you have less RAM

  Do note that for dual channel tri channel RAM, you need multiples of
  2 or 3 sticks of RAM respectively to work.
- If that does not work, you can try running the program in a VM. There are other VM
  options than MS VM and XP mode. A popular free VM software is
  [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)
- If you do not have a copy of a compatible OS then you can also try
  installing Linux on a VM, or install 32 bit Linux on your machine,
  and run that program under Wine